# Every extremally disconnected space is a perfectly $\kappa$-normal space.

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is called perfectly $\kappa$-normal if the closure of any open
set is a zero-set.

Is it true that every extremally disconnected space is perfectly $\kappa$-normal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Yes. Suppose that $X$ is extremally disconnected, and let $U$ be an open set in $X$. Then $\cl U$ is open and therefore clopen, and every clopen set in any space is a zero-set: just define $f:X\to \Bbb R$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x\in U$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in X\setminus U$.

Comment: Reading failure on my part.

Comment: @Arthur: You had me worried for a minute! :-)