# Regularly open, co-zero sets in compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

It follows from the definition of a completely regular space that such spaces have a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) consisting of co-zero sets, that is, sets whose complement is the zero set of some real-valued, continuous function.

On the other hand, it is not hard to show that regularly open sets also form a base. (A set is regularly open if it is equal to the interior of its closure.) So my question is

> Does every compact Hausdorff space have a base which consists of sets which are simultaneously regularly open and co-zero?

Of course, the question is meaningful for spaces which are not metrisable (or more generally, not [perfectly $\kappa$-normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312694/every-extremally-disconnected-space-is-a-perfectly-kappa-normal-space)).

I am not really interested in special cases, but in full generality.

Comment: By [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/a/73999/5810), a yes answer to your question would require at least some of [AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice). ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, I feel no fear for AC.

Comment: A partial result: in Fremlin Measure Theory volume 4, theorem 443N (can be found online), it is shown that if $X$ is a topological group carrying a Haar measure (so e.g. a locally compact such group) any regular open set is a cozero set.